# Oracle db_name, db_unique_name, and ORACLE_HOME

Tags: oracle, database-design

I'm studying Oracle and I would like to understand the uniqueness or constrains when assigning these parameters.

Suppose a machine with a single OS (host) and 2 different databases (physical). Are they forced to use different db_name in following cases?

- They share ORACLE_HOME
- They don't share ORACLE_HOME

How is this related when db_unique_name enters in the game? What's the point?

So far reading in Forums and offical Docs I got the following assumption :

**EDITED**

This is what created me confusion: http://www.mail-archive.com/oracle-l@fatcity.com/msg10241.html

Then, you could have following situations:

- Repeated DB_NAME is not possible within the same ORACLE_HOME (no matter OS and SID) for the DB_NAME is stenciled onto the files for that DB. There are 2 exceptions (Parallel Server/RAC though they are indeed different instances of the same database, and Primary-Standby systems, where need a common DB_NAME and Oracle provides us with the DB_UNIQUE_NAME mechanism)
- For different ORACLE_HOMEs, it is possible as each installation does not see the other and they don't conflict when sharing DB_NAME, but is strongly undesirable. Besides, on Windows, every instance is mapped to a service OracleService%SID%, so that makes impossible to have two different SIDs on the same OS, even if an instance ID is defined as ORACLE_HOME + ORACLE_SID. But as by default (and it's an ORACLE recommendation for conventional setups) DB_NAME = SID, even in different ORACLE_HOME, 2 databases in Windows are likely to fail due to a SID default name that is common (so the second service cannot be created).

... but more authoritative answers are still welcome!

Comment: Just in practice is better to avoid using the same name for different databases. Even on different servers. You will never know when the names will collide - Enterprise Manager, backups, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have 2 databases with the same db_name on the same system on linux in the same ORACLE_HOME. You just have to make sure that the instance name differs. EG different pfile/spfile,... It's just not advised to give them the same name...
   When running the runinstaller you just give them the same global name and a different SID. 
   --> Not sure how Windows reacts on it.
2. The reason why the db_name has to be the same in a **primary-standby** setup is because the name is "imprinted" on the datafiles. The db_unique_name is mandatory in order to make a difference between the databases and to setup a syncing. The recovery would be impossible if you use a different db_name

Comment: So same db_name on Linux with shared ORACLE_HOME possible, does it happen the same in the other combinations Linux - diff ORACLE_HOME, Win - shared HOME, Win - diff HOME?

Comment: It won't differ on a different ORACLE_HOME on same linux. Though I wouldn't know what would happen if you used the same SID. Theoretically it should be possible. I don't know forsure what the impact would be on a windows environment either. But I reckon there won't be any difference.

Comment: Why aren't you testing this on your own? Seeing that you are studying "Oracle" assuming the dba aspect. You can find great VM's delivered by Oracle which are preconfigured.

Comment: I am posting from my job, and I cannot obviously install 4 oracles and 2 SO here. It is just a theory thing I have seen answered in contradiction in plenty of sites. Just want to benefit from someone else's knowledge before I run into buying a better domestic PC (1 gb RAM, Ubuntu), a disk, and 2 SO

Comment: Just a final doubt then. If the db_name is printed in datafiles, how can it be possible to have 2 databases with the same name just by writing different SIDs? Wouldn't be that 2 instances of the same database?

Comment: Besides, I assumed that db_name is the X in CREATE DATABASE X, so how can it be possible even with different SIDs, to share same db_name in a single ORACLE_HOME?